# .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) lagging my UI

Tags: android, user-interface

How slow is that method, really? I have a ListView and a custom adapter, which populates my list with the following sample XML:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <TextView />
    <View />
    <TextView />
    <RelativeLayout>
        <View android:id="@+id/1" />      <--Take note of this one
        <TextView android:id="@+id/2" />  <--And this one too
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The ListView itself runs smoothly, scrolls well and loading is not really an issue. The functionality of the ListView includes toggling the visibility of the two nested Views (the ones that I marked to take note of) when the row is clicked; by default, they are set with the property:

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

What I do is I check for the visibility of the two Views and toggle their visibility status accordingly, for example as such:

```
View v = findViewById(R.id.1);
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.2);

if (v.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
    v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} else {
    v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Now, all this happens fine, and there are no bugs. The views get toggled accordingly. But the question here is, why is it that the UI is so SLOW? I've tried commenting out the code line by line, and it is very apparent the two setVisibility() methods are to blame. Is it always so slow, and is there a way I can speed things up?

Also, I can't simply toggle the visibility of the RelativeLayout wrapper, I need to be able to control the two inner views separately. The above is just example code, but it's very similar to what I currently have.

Help appreciated!

Thanks,
Rei

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure about that, but if you have many elements on your list, then system need to process all of them and make them Visible. This is the reason why it can take so much time. Did you try instead of using GONE use INVISIBLE?

Comment: Making them INVISIBLE did indeed speed up the process, but I still don't get it: why is this happening?

Comment: If you make View invisible it is like making it totally transparent. If you make it gone, if has to disappear from the layout, which makes the operation take longer time. I am just guessing. Also you can try to use advice provided by Sandeep, maybe it will speed up a little.

Comment: I just stumbled upon this - the slowness in my case had to to with remeasuring & redrawing entire ui - GONE elements trigger layout invalidation, while INVISIBLE do not. Huge performance boost in my case.

Answer (score -4):

Instead of `View.VISIBLE` try using `View.VISIBLE` and `View.GONE`.